# example of a partially ordered vector space

Tags: sequences-and-series, vector-lattices

Are there any well known examples of partially ordered vector spaces (Riesz Spaces) from applied or pure mathematics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The space $l^p$ of all $p$-integrable (resp. bounded if $p = \infty$ sequences is a Riesz space for $1 \le p \le \infty$.
- The space $C([a,b])$ of all continuous functions on the interval $[a,b]$ is a Riesz space.
- Any $L^p(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ space [with a measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$]  is a Riesz space for $1 \le p \le \infty$.
- $C_b(X)$ the space of all continuous bounded real functions on a topological space $X$ is a Riesz space.
- The set of all measurable functions $m(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is a Riesz space. (Modulo nullsets, as always.)
- The set of all $M_\sigma(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$ of all finite signed $\sigma$-additive measures is a Riesz space.
- Similar the $M_{\rm{add}}(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$ of all finitely additive measures is also a Riesz space.

Comment: for the case of C([a,b])  wouldn't that be a trivial riesz space as it's fully ordered?

Comment: What means 'fully ordered'? $C([a,b])$ is not totally ordered! For example take $a=0$, $b=1$ and $f(x) = 1/2 -x$ and $g(x) = x-1/2$, then $f(1) = -1/2 < 1/2 = g(1)$, but $f(0) =1/2 > -1/2 = g(0)$.

Comment: Thanks, this helped clarify the nature of ordering for me.  Perhas a better question would be what are examples of the ordering function "<=".